# Multiple simultaneous XMPP connections using Strophe and Openfire

Tags: xmpp, strophe

I was wondering if anybody has experience using a single javascript client to establish multiple connections to an Openfire server over BOSH.  It seems like if I try to establish more than 4 or 5 connections, Strophe.connect.status goes to CONNFAIL randomly and clients start dropping/reconnecting randomly.

Answer (score 1):

Many browsers limit the number of simultaneous connections you can have to a given site.  You're likely running into that limit.